# open photo gallery on second tab bar click?

Tags: iphone

How do I open a photo gallery on second tab bar click??

Comment: how many tab bars do you have?? Please give more details.

Comment: one tabbar having two tabs.. i want to open the photo gallery on second tab click..

Answer (score 1):

You should probabbly implement **UITabBarControllerDelegate**

```
– tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:
– tabBarController:didSelectViewController:
```